# QMessageBox "show details"

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

When you open a `QMessageBox` with detailed text set it has the *show details* button. I would like the details to be displayed by default, rather than the user having to click on the *Show Details...* button first.

[image: qt_doc_example]

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell from a quick look through [the source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp.html), there is is no easy way to directly open the details text, or indeed access the "Show Details..." button. The best method I could find was to:

1. Iterate through all buttons on the message box.
2. Extract the one with the role `ActionRole`, as this corresponds to the "Show Details..." button.
3. Call the `click` method manually on this.

A code sample of this in action:

```
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setText("Some text");
    messageBox.setDetailedText("More details go here");

    // Loop through all buttons, looking for one with the "ActionRole" button
    // role. This is the "Show Details..." button.
    QAbstractButton *detailsButton = NULL;

    foreach (QAbstractButton *button, messageBox.buttons()) {
        if (messageBox.buttonRole(button) == QMessageBox::ActionRole) {
            detailsButton = button;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If we have found the details button, then click it to expand the
    // details area.
    if (detailsButton) {
        detailsButton->click();
    }

    // Show the message box.
    messageBox.exec();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your example did not work for me.  When I iterate through the buttons, it only finds the standard buttons (e.g., "Yes" and "No").  The "Show Details" button was not among them at the time I was crawling through them.  Using Qt version 4.7.4.

Comment: Not sure sorry - from memory I tested this on Qt 5.x. Maybe try looking through each `QAbstractButton` child of the message box using a recursive `findChildren` call?

Comment: Yes, I had tried searching for the "Show Details" button via `findChildren()` also.  I can indeed find that "Show Details" button in that way, but its role at the time I find it is `InvalidRole`.  I called `click()` on that button anyway, just to see what would happen.  It had no effect.

Comment: You can fuse the last if with the loop:

```
    QAbstractButton *detailsButton = nullptr;
    foreach (QAbstractButton *button, messageBox.buttons())
    {
        if (messageBox.buttonRole(button) == QMessageBox::ActionRole)
        {
            detailsButton = button;
            detailsButton->click(); // click it to expand the text
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This function will expand the details by default and also resize the text box to a bigger size:

```
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QAbstractButton>

void showDetailsInQMessageBox(QMessageBox& messageBox)
{
    foreach (QAbstractButton *button, messageBox.buttons())
    {
        if (messageBox.buttonRole(button) == QMessageBox::ActionRole)
        {
            button->click();
            break;
        }
    }
    QList<QTextEdit*> textBoxes = messageBox.findChildren<QTextEdit*>();
    if(textBoxes.size())
        textBoxes[0]->setFixedSize(750, 250);
}

...  //somewhere else

QMessageBox box;
showDetailsInQMessageBox(box);
```

Answer (score 1):

On Qt5 at least:

```cpp
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Some text");
    msgBox.setDetailedText(text);

    // Search the "Show Details..." button
    foreach (QAbstractButton *button, msgBox.buttons())
    {
        if (msgBox.buttonRole(button) == QMessageBox::ActionRole)
        {
            button->click(); // click it to expand the text
            break;
        }
    }

    msgBox.exec();
```